# Change offline maps directory to SD. HERE-Maps SDK

Tags: android, here-api

How can we change the directory to download the map. By default it is internal storage. But I need the user to select the download directory (device/SD).

I tried to use setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath method. When I use SECONDARY_STORAGE path, SDK is not initialized. When I use EXTERNAL_STORAGE directory successfully changed, but this directory is located in the device memory ("/storage/emulated/0").

```
      com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
                System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")+"/heremap"
                , "MyHereMapService");
```

Manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="MyHereMapService"
        android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MyHereMapService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

UPDATE:
I was able to get the real path to SD. I use method ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(activity, null), which return real path to SD card (secondary storage).

Comment: `.. to download the map`. Which map?

Comment: @greenapps , HERE maps. SDK allows you to download and save maps in device memory .(by default). But i want to change default directory.

Comment: What does System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") return? I would not expect it to be set on most devices.

Comment: @DavidLeong, System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") return "/storage/extSdCard". And on the other device return "/storage/sdcard1". And on both devices SDK does not init.

Comment: Does your app have  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @DavidLeong, Yes, app have write and read external storage permissions.

Comment: @DavidLeong, I was able to change cache directory to sd. I use ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(activity, null) method, which return path to Secondary storage. But I don't know default here-map cache directory. I wont to change cache directory between default and custom. What can be done?

Comment: There is no default directory if you are using the isolated diskcache API. It will cache to whatever folder you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: There is a possibility to change cache directory to sd. User choose ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(activity, null) method, which return path to Secondary storage. 
Concerning the default here-map cache directory: There is no default directory if you are using the isolated disk cache API. It will cache to whatever folder you have specified.